# Corrupt double encoding with Portugese

Tags: utf-8, iso-8859-1, iconv, mb-convert-encoding

I have a database that has a lot of corrupt entries, such as:

```
IVAM BENEDITO GONÃƒALVES DE QUEIROZ
```

I have tried several encoding conversion to no avail. I've found other reports where by the characters **Ãƒ** should be **Ã**. However in this case **Ãƒ** should be **Ç**.

Does anyone have any idea how to successfully convert this? At current I am going through locating the problem characters and replacing the with REPLACE().

Comment: In this case, **Ãf** should be **Ç** (if it was **Z**, you wouldn't get this error). Try using the iso 8859-1 or 2. These are the isos we use with portuguese language. FYI: this **ç**, we call "cedilha", has the sound of the **c** in greece, for example. https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp

Comment: Yeah, that should have been Ç. I've tried converting to various char sets and nothing works. I think this has been encoded twice as the wrong char set or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the specific problem, but these replacements fixed the data:

```
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ãƒ','ç' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ãƒ%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã€','A ' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã€%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â©','ú' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â©%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â”œÃ¼','A' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â”œÃ¼%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â”œÃ©','A' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â”œÃ©%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã©','A' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã©%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â±','é' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â±%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ãº','ú' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ãº%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Âº','í' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Âº%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â³','ú' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â³%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã´','é' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã´%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã¶','ê' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã¶%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â”œÃ§','ç' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â”œÃ§%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â¤','á' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â¤%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'ZÂ¡','á' ) WHERE name LIKE '%ZÂ¡%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â¡','ó' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â¡%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã½','ç' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã½%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â”¼','é' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â”¼%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â¾','á' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â¾%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã˜','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã˜%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã˜','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã˜%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã‰','é' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã‰%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã‡','ç' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã‡%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â•”','é' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â•”%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã•','ú' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã•%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â•','í' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â•%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã‚Â¶','ã' ), name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã‚Âµ','á' ), name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã‚','' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã‚Â%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Âµ','ñ' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Âµ%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ãœ','ü' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ãœ%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â”œ','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â”œ%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã«','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã«%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã”','õ' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã”%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â¨','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â¨%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'ÃŒ','â' ) WHERE name LIKE '%ÃŒ%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â°','é' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â°%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã¦','í' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã¦%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â¥','ú' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â¥%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â¿','ó' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â¿%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã—','ç' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã—%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â”¬Ã‚','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â”¬Ã‚%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã‚','â' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã‚%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'ãÃ¢','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%ãÃ¢%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'ZÂ£','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%ZÂ£%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Â£','ú' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Â£%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'ZÂ¢','ã' ) WHERE name LIKE '%ZÂ¢%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'ãâ”‚','ó' ) WHERE name LIKE '%ãâ”‚%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'ãÂ¢','ç' ) WHERE name LIKE '%ãÂ¢%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'áâ”Â¢','ç' ) WHERE name LIKE '%áâ”Â¢%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'â”¬â”‚','a ' ) WHERE name LIKE '%â”¬â”‚%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'ç£','í' ) WHERE name LIKE '%ç£%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, '¶','õ' ) WHERE name LIKE '%¶%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, '§','ú' ) WHERE name LIKE '%§%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, '¾','ó' ) WHERE name LIKE '%¾%';
UPDATE Brazil SET name = REPLACE( name, 'Ã','ç' ) WHERE name LIKE '%Ã%';
```